# Solving $m^3 \equiv n^6 \pmod{19}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm studying for a first year Discrete Mathematics course, I found this question on a previous paper and am lost on how to solve:

> Let $n$ be a fixed arbitrary integer, prove that there are infinitely
>   many integers $m$ s.t.: $m^3 \equiv n^6 \pmod{19}$

Thank you

Comment: 1) If there is any $m^3 \equiv n^6 \pmod {19}$ then $m + 19k$ for all integers $k$ so there are infinitely many solutions.  So 2) Prove that the is at least one solution.  3) Don't worry about proving this for $n^6$.  Prove it for *any* integer $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $n$ is given, you take $m=n^2$. This satisfies the congruence $m^3 \equiv n^6 \pmod{19}$. Now to generate infinitely many integer solutions, set $m_k=n^2+19k$, where $k \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) wrt primitive root $g$

$3$ind$_gm\equiv6$ind$_gn\pmod{\phi(19)}$

$\iff$ind$_gm\equiv2$ind$_gn\pmod6$

$\implies m=n^2g^{6k}$ where $k\equiv0,1,2\pmod3$

As $2^4\equiv-3,2^9\equiv2(-3)^2\equiv-1\pmod{19},g$ can be chosen to be $2$